# Update error on Eclipse for PHP Developers with unknown Host error

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

My operating system is 'Ubuntu 12.04 LTS' and have been using **Eclipse for PHP Developers**.
I'm getting error with dialog box that says

```
A problem occured while accessing the update site.
See 'Details' for more information.
```

The description of error

```
A problem occurred while accessing the update site.
RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
Unknown Host: http://il-studiosrv1/studio-eclipse/updates-extra/9_0//pdt_directory.xml
il-studiosrv1
```

There is not anything on web which could have helped me.

May be the address of host don't have proper format that is why the error is being displayed. If the message is ignored, it disappears but every time 'Eclipse for PHP Developers' is loaded then the dialog box re-appears.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you download 'Eclipse for PHP Developers'?
OpenDNS let me know here is a similar issue.
http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=74803
And I could reproduce the problem with eclipse-php-3.0.2.v20120611144-Win32.zip. This is a failure by Zend.
If you are using 'Zend Eclipse PDT' and you must use such a collapsed product, go to Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites, find h ttp://il-studiosrv1/... and remove it for now. (or replace "il-studiosrv1" with "downloads.zend.com" for trial)

Comment: The error discussed on the forum (you've provide) looks similar but the descriptions are different however I've followed your instruction. The PDT was downloaded from http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt/downloads. Thank You for replying